# Is it possible to exclude field on firestore index?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just watched the playlist of [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ), and I just learned that every field of the document is indexed.

My question is, is there way for a certain fields to be excluded on by Firestore indexing? Something like fields that I am pretty sure that I will not be using as a query lookup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you correctly found, Firestore automatically indexes all individual fields of the documents in the collection. You can exclude certain fields from the [single field indexes panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/firestore/indexes/single-field/manage) in the Firebase console.

From there:

> Cloud Firestore creates the indexes defined by your automatic index settings for each field you add, enabling most simple queries by default. You can add exemptions to manually set how a specific field is indexed.

From there, you can enter the collection (or collection group), and the field name, and then select which indexes (ascending, descending, arrays) get auto-created or not.

Comment: Thank you. It look like it need to manually set the excluded fields, that will make impossible to exclude dynamic fields, am I right? The only possible solution I can think of for excluding dynamic fields is to put them inside a ```map```, then exclude the map itself. Other than that is there another way doing it? I was thinking like ```annotations``` or (for Node/JS/Web) an object with an extra array of string field with the values of ```field names``` that will tell Firestore to exclude it.

Comment: The documentation says "If you create a single-field index exemption for a map field, the map's subfields inherit those settings."